# regular expression/ BeanShell post processor time will add in transaction response time

Tags: performance, jmeter

I am new to Jmeter...could any one please let me know is regular expression/ BeanShell post processor time will add in transaction response time?

I have http requests where one request have 3 regular expression and one BeanShell post processor time and for measuring response time i have use transaction controller.

Comment: answer to your question is no, jmeter excludes external execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the regular expression and BeanShell post processor won't add transaction response time.

Comment: Thanks for the Update....could you plz let me know in load runner correlation functions add the time if stop transaction was not used in response time...and Jmeter we used regular expression for correlation then it would take some time to find the required text  then that time is not added....also BeanShell post processor take small time to run the "code" then that is also not added?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in your Transaction Controller which called `Include duration of timer and pre-post processors in generated sample`

Unless you have it set to `true` your post-processors and timers **won't be included** into transaction metrics.

See [Using JMeter's Transaction Controller](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) guide for more details.